# Nodejs require config

Tags: node.js

I am writing Nodejs at this moment and I was wondering what is better for requiring configuration:

1. In my main file I require conf.js only once and then pass it to the other files `require('./jwt)(config)`
2. In every file where I need something from the config I require it

Which one is better? I think it's the first one but I have some files that are used by the controllers (eg. jwt.js - veryfy and create token). Is it a *best practise* to require this module in the main file (where I don't need it) and pass the config or to use the second way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling main file in every files then 1st one is better no need to add

```
var LatLonModule = require('conf.js');
```

in every file.

else you can choose 2nd option

Comment: I run the main file (it's the server.js) and I want to register the plugins. I don't require the main.

Comment: then you can call conf.js separate in all file where you required  conf.js file functionality

Comment: then I should use the second option?

Comment: yes as per my understanding .. please make vote up if you thing this answer is helpful for you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131369/discussion-between-kirpt-and-khushvinder).